# Workbench moderation repeats "Save and " in the button labels

Tags: 8, workbench

My workbench moderation label is, for example, *Save as draft*, but the button says *Save and Save as Draft*.  How can I get rid of that *Save and* , which is repeated for every button?

Comment: You can't, just choose a transition name that fits with the prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Save and** has been hardcoded in the Workbench Moderation module.